# Using CSS Clip-Path to Create a Skewed Background on Menu Item?

Tags: html, css

Hi and thank you in advance for your help. I've been messing with this for days but can't figure it out. I'm trying to get a skewed box/parallelogram colored background behind the active/hover menu items and can't get it to size properly.

My code is:
#header .main-menu > li.menu-item.active {background-color: #fdb819; clip-path: polygon(66% 20%, 100% 20%, 33% 80%, 0 80%);}

How it currently looks;

[image: how it currently looks]

The above image is what I'm getting. The yellow background is way too narrow and doesn't "fill" the space behind the text. Can anyone please help me fix this?

I've tried so many different things that I can't even remember now. I want it to look similar to this example when finished:

What I want it to look like:

[image: what I want it to look like]

Answer (score 0):

I would not be inclined to rely on a `clip-path` for this particular purpose. I would go with background gradients. There are several kinds to choose from for this, you could do it with 2 or 3 gradients, I chose to do it with 2 `linear-gradient`s that start transparent at an angle and then use the yellow in question. And they need to be sized to be half of the element's width. In that way it will work if the size of the element is longer or shorter. It could also be done with a combination of `conic-gradient`s too.

```css
section#header {
  background: #fff;
}

ul.main-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2ch;
}

ul.main-menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2ch 4ch;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

#header .main-menu>li.menu-item.active a, #header .main-menu>li.menu-item.active a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-position: 0 0, top 0 right 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 115deg, transparent 25px, #fdb819 0), linear-gradient( -65deg, transparent 25px, #fdb819 0);
}

#header .main-menu>li.menu-item a:hover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 100%;
  background-position: 0 0, top 0 right 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 115deg, transparent 25px, #ccc 0), linear-gradient( -65deg, transparent 25px, #ccc 0);
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="main-menu">
      <li class="menu-item active"><a href="#">SHOP ALL PARTS</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">DRIVER INFO</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">LIVE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```